# No client/build folder created when i run "npm run build" with vuejs app as frontend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy client and server code to heroku from a single git repo. when I run "npm run build" I get this :

[image]

But there is no folder being created so I can't deploy the app.

Here are my package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
```

},

And here is my code to let our Express server know to serve our project:

```
(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", "../../client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "../../client/build", "/public/index.html")
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: It says `The ..\server\public directoy is ready to be deployed.` Adjust your express server to that path.

Answer (score 1):

Install Heroku CLI

Create a static.json file:

```
{
  "root": "dist",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Add static.json file to git

```
git add static.json
git commit -m "add static configuration"
```

Deploy to Heroku

```
heroku login
heroku create
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static
git push heroku master
```